# IllegalAccessError thrown by new ChromeDriver() on OSX (Java)

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

Getting this under Eclipse straight out of the gate.

Code:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver" ,  "/path/to/selenium/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Throws Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.<init>(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)V from class org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.<init>(UrlChecker.java:67)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:190)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:171)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:124)
```

OSX 10.12
Selenium 3.4
ChromeDriver 2.31

Comment: So, does the browser start? Are you sure error is thrown at line `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` ? Does the user have right permissions on `/path/to/selenium/chromedriver` directory?

Comment: @IvanPronin (a) Of course not; (b) see the stack trace for proof; (c) user permissions are irrelevant: see the Javadoc of `IllegalAccessError`.

Comment: Same happens to me on windows.

Comment: try `RemoteWebDriver` instead `ChromeDriver`

Answer (score 19):

Setting this back to 22.0 helped for me.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>22.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, @Walter. This will likely break the Firefox driver, but I will certainly try and report back.

Comment: Walter where did you set this? In pom.xml?

Answer (score 5):

> Setting this back to 22.0 helped for me.

Version 22.0 didn't fix the problem for me, but 19.0 did.

```
compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '19.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

the main problem is you have a jar conflict.

selenium has compile dependency on guava, you can find this at: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver/3.141.0

[image]

if you project has another version of `guava`, it may use wrong `guava` version.

to exclude duplicate dependency in maven, you can add right guava version explicitly, in this case:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>25.0-jre</version>
</dependency>
```