# Selenium cucumber framework , chrome not launching

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I have created selenium cucumber framework , with junit n jdk 1.8, but below error coming in console n chrome not launching. Same code work well at home network. Not working in office

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.<init>(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)V from class org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker

       at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.<init>(UrlChecker.java:67)

       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:190)

       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:181)

       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)

       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)

       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)

       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)

       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)

       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:184)

       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:171)

       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:124)

       at stepDefinition.Dashboard.Open_chrome(Dashboard.java:19)

       at ?.Given Open chrome(dashboard.feature:4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of guava are you using? I've had same problem with guava version 23.0 and set to 22.0 and it's working fine.

There's similar question with answers: [IllegalAccessError thrown by new ChromeDriver() on OSX (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45643956/illegalaccesserror-thrown-by-new-chromedriver-on-osx-java)